# Find and return first matching element of an array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a simple function that should return the first element of an array that matches my criteria using a for loop. It keeps returning the first element of the array whether it meets the set criteria or not. Any idea where the bug is here? I also tried the .find() method, same issue.

```
function wheresTheBeef(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if  (array[i] == 'fillet' || 'strip' || 'sirloin') {
      return array[i];
    }
    else {
      return 'there is no beef!'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the array content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **2 problems** here.

1. Your if checking is wrong, because `array[i] == 'fillet' || 'strip' || 'sirloin'` will always **TRUE**
2. And you should not return directly in else branch, otherwise your code logic is only checking for first element

```js
function wheresTheBeef(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if  (array[i] == 'fillet' || array[i] == 'strip' || array[i] == 'sirloin') {
      return array[i];
    }
    else {
      continue
    }
  }
  return "there is no beef"
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I can help you

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is incorrect, change this:

```
if  (array[i] == 'fillet' || 'strip' || 'sirloin') {
```

for this one:

```
if  (array[i] == 'fillet' || array[i] == 'strip' || array[i] == 'sirloin') {
```

Reason of the change:

```js
let var1="something";

if (var1) {
  console.log("var1 has a truthy value");
}

if (1==0 || "something") {
  console.log("condition is true");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to test each element with the string, because every single non empty string is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```
if (array[i] === 'fillet' || array[i] === 'strip' || array[i] === 'sirloin') {
```

Nearly the same with [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
found = array.find(item => ['fillet', 'strip', 'sirloin'].includes(item));
```

Answer (score 0):

so you just need to get rid of the second return statement (and the else). As soon as you `return`, execution will stop. So if you never return, the loop will continue until it is satisfied.

If you still need the `there is no beef` statement, you can put it outside the loop. If the loop executes and the condition is never satisfied, then it will proceed to return that statement.